# how to navigate and set values checked in dropdown in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have two components namely ComponentA and ComponentB. In componentB, there is a link which when clicked should navigate to ComponentA and send data to ComponentA. The values in the data should be set to the dropdown in ComponentA.

**The code in ComponentB**

```
  this.router.navigate(['/component-a], {
    queryParams: {
      _series: obj.name1,
      _accyName: this.name2,
      _accyNum: this.name3
    }
  });
```

**The Code in Component A html**

```
<ss-multiselect-dropdown name="modelYear" id="modelYear" [(ngModel)]="this.modelYear" [texts]="selectTextSettings"
                    [settings]="multiSelectSettings" [options]="modelYearOptions"></ss-multiselect-dropdown>
```

**The Code in Component A component.ts** (in ngOnInit)

```
this.modelYear.push(this.dataFromComponentB.modelYear)
```

I could able to navigate and get the values from ComponentB but it is not possible to set it the dropdowns in ComponentA. How to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

in ComponentA

```
ngOnInit() {
     // retrieve if available
    this._series = this.route.queryParams['_series'];
    // now add series to your dropdown array
}
```

Comment: what value / object you have in this.dataFromComponentB.modelYear and this.modelYear ? if possible share with details